# Loop allocation of linked list inside inline struct not allocating memory

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, structure, inline

I have strange problem with allocating a linked list in a loop.

Consider a simplified source code :

```
struct main_s {
    minor_s minor_structure; (inline)
};

struct minor_s {
    list_s *first_dir;
};

struct list_s {
    anotherlist_s *first_object;
    list_s *next;
};

struct anotherlist_s {
    //multiple fields
};
```

And i have a basic init/deinit functions like :

```
struct main_s *main_s_init();
void main_s_deinit();
```

And now i'm kinda riddled with allocating in loop :

```
im passing to this function main_s->minor_structure.first_dir and, how_many parameter, defining how many linked nodes going to be initiated.

void loop_inittiation(struct list_s *list, int how_many) {
    int i;
    struct list_s *tmp = list;
    for(i = 0; i < how_many; i++) {
        tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct list_s));
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}
```

And this is where i have problem, im allocating the temporary "tmp" instead of the pointed structure. I understand that to allocate a pointer by tmp u have to use double pointer, but it still doesnt work. What am i missing? In gdb there is no memory space allocated :/.
Do i have to use **tmp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got the right idea about what's wrong.  The local copy of tmp in the function is changed, but once you're outside, that value is lost.  If you want to change a variable inside a different function in C, you MUST pass the address of the thing you want to change.  If the thing you want to change is already a pointer, you must pass the address of the pointer (or double pointer).  If it's a double pointer you want to change, then you have to pass a triple pointer.  If it's a 123141 pointer, you have to pass a 123142 pointer :)

Change the parameter to the function to:

```
&(main_s->minor_structure.first_dir)
```

Just change the input parameter to

```
struct list **list
```

change tmp to a double pointer to match it, then each time you use tmp, make sure to throw in an extra dereference..

```
struct list_s **tmp = list
```

and

```
*tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct list_s));
*tmp = (*tmp)->next;
```

So it would look like:

```
void loop_inittiation(struct list_s **list, int how_many) {
    int i;
    struct list_s **tmp = list;
    for(i = 0; i < how_many; i++) {
        *tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct list_s));
        tmp = &((**tmp)->next);
    }
}
```

Another way to do it is to leave the tmp stuff alone, as a single pointer, store the first node you allocate, and then just say

```
*list = tmp;
```

But then you do have to treat that first allocation as a special case.

Comment: Well it didn't work in this example unfortunately, i get error request for member 'next' in something not a structure or union. Will try to figure that out.

Comment: Even if type *tmp = ((*tmp)->next); it compiles but only rewrites the 1st node of the list in the structure, not stepping into next.

Comment: Should it be tmp = &((**tmp)->next)?